# Syntax Error Insert into statement visual C# and ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

Every time I try to run, error pop ups saying

> Syntax Error Insert Into

I've tried changing the statement by putting [] braces as there are no reserved keyword.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO lectrical([ItemName],Type,Quantity,Retail,Sale) value('"+ txtItemName.Text +` `"','" + txtType.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text) + "','" +` `Convert.ToDecimal(txtRetail.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtSale.Text) +` `"') ";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this part of query:

```
"INSERT INTO lectrical([ItemName],Type,Quantity,Retail,Sale) value(..."
```

You wrote `value` - should be `values`. Also, `Type` should be in `[]`, it is reserved keyword.

Your query should be:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO lectrical(ItemName,[Type],Quantity,Retail,Sale) values('"+ txtItemName.Text +` `"','" + txtType.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text) + "','" +` `Convert.ToDecimal(txtRetail.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtSale.Text) +` `"') ";
```